# C# WriteFile(), unable to write to USB HID device

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# as well as windows programming and I am attempting to establish communication between a USB HID device. I got  the device path successfully using 'SetupDiGetDevicexxxxxx' and used 'CreateFile()' to get Handle. Below is my code.

```
public const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
public const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
public const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
public const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
CreateFile(string Devicepath)
{
    HidHandle = CreateFile(Devicepath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);                     
}
```

After obtaining Device handle info, I am  calling write file functions as below.

```
Result = WriteFile(HidHandle, outputReportBuffer[], outputReportBuffer.Length, NumberOfBytesWritten, 0);
```

Outputbuffer is the byte array of length 8. For some reason, I was not able to write to USB HID device. "Result" is always zero. Any Help is appreciated. Also, can any one tell me how to verify that `HidHandle` is a valid or not. When I run the program I am  getting it as "1124".

I did followed previous post on this type of question: [Cannot communicate successfully with USB HID device using writefile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691619/cannot-communicate-successfully-with-usb-hid-device-using-writefile), but no help.

Below are the two menthods for create file and writefile.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, uint lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, uint hTemplateFile );    

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static public extern bool WriteFile(int hFile,  byte lpBuffer, int nNumberOfBytesToWrite,  int lpNumberOfBytesWritten, int lpOverlapped)
```

Comment: Modify your source to support a call to GetLastError, and post the results. Out of curiosity, why are you using Win32 API's for this effort, rather than native .NET API calls?

Comment: Do you see this device as drive inside windows explorer?

Comment: Hello David, I have used ,ErrorStatus = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();But is not returning any thing.All I can see is ErrorStatus is 0 after debugging.

Comment: Hello Gregor, Yes I can see this device under system "Device Manager"

Comment: Modify your WriteFile call to include [DllImport("kernel32.dll"),SetLastError=true].

Comment: @user1668957 its ok if you see device under device manager. But is device accessable as drive (like d,e,f,... disk)?

Comment: Hello David, I did as you said, Error status is showing "998". what does this mean??

Comment: Hello Gregor, This is microchip starter kit from "Microchip". I don't see any thing like that.Is that the issue.If so,how to resolve this.Please let me know.

Comment: Hello Gregor, Just to know, for any USB HID device, is it must that that device should be recognized as a drive inside windows explorer.Let me know

Comment: Any advice please on this. Thanks

Comment: Does any one guide me how to get/show USB device as a drive under windows explorer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Gregor, I think it is not necessary to show drive under windows explorer.from other person, I came to know that shd be come from chip itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to use a USB library, like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/libusbsharp/)

Comment: Hi ALexandre, Thanks for reply. I am not aware of this USB library. I don't know how to use it.actually I am following example from "FLORIAN LEITNER". But stuck with write file.

Comment: LibUsb is massive overkill. The OP is on the right path. With Hid devices, you can simply open up a file handle with CreateFile and write to the file. You can definitely do the same with some USB devices, but other devices inexplicably fail. The real question is what LibUsb actually does that's so different.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is some reason why you are dipping into such low level Win32 functions, but I would advise if you just want to write a file somewhere just use the File class within .net.

If you are just wanting to write bytes then one of the simplest ways is to use File.WriteAllBytes() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx

Comment: Hello Grofit, Thanks for EMail. I am writing to a USB HID device, where the first byte should be a report ID. I will try to implement as mentioned.

Comment: I dont know why im down voted, I am not the only person wondering why there needs to even be a thought about win32 api when writing files unless the problem is not about writing files and instead about streaming data to a device, which is a different question.

Comment: Hello Grofit, I am not the person who has voted you down. I will try to run the code as mentioned and if it helps me i will give you thumbs up.

Comment: But the question remains, how do you write those bytes to a USB device?