# how to see USB HID device as drive inside windows explorer

Tags: c#

I have USB HID microchip.I got its VID,PID and device path and device handle. In order to write to it, do I need to see drive in windows explorer.When I call Write function I am getting error as "998". what does this mean. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see your usb device as a drive, it must implement the USB MSD (Mass storage device) profile. USB HID (human interface device) profile is for devices such as keyboard and mouse.
This has to do with the code in your microchip, not with c# on your PC.

Comment: Hello Alexandre, But I still have the problem with writing to the USB HID device.Would you please answer to the post in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673875/c-sharp-writefile-unable-to-write-to-usb-hid-device". Thanks a lot