# pInvoke method for GUID in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, guid, unsafe

I am new to C# and USB programming. I am having several issues with it. I am  not able to communicate with it.Here is how I am declaring GUID to get GUID. I am creating a new instance of GUID and then calling HidGuid to get Guid.Below are pInvoke methods for it.But how to verify GUID I am getting is valid/correct.Is there any way to convert this structure in to a string. If so, how. Let me know. Thanks.

```
private GUID MYguid = new GUID();
HidGuid();

public unsafe void CT_HidGuid()
// 1.Data1 = 1293833650
//Data2 = 61807
//Data3 = 4559
//data4 = 136 203 0 17 17 0 0 48
// hex values  4d1e55b2 f16f 11cf 7be03c74ac80
{                              
    HidD_GetHidGuid(ref MYguid);  
}
[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe void HidD_GetHidGuid(ref GUID lpHidGuid);

public unsafe struct GUID
{
    public int Data1;
    public System.UInt16 Data2;.
    public System.UInt16 Data3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] data4; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard System.Guid type? `HidD_GetHidGuid(ref System.Guid lpHidGuid);`

Comment: if you just want to make your GUID into a string, override the ToString() method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you really need to use PInvoke to generate a GUID? Why no using Guid.NewGuid() method from System namespace?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

Comment: I tried it. I am getting another GUID. How to confirm which one is valid and correct. you can see from the above structure, GUID is (hex values)  4d1e55b2 f16f 11cf 7be03c74ac80 where as If I follow as said in mSDN I am getting another one.

Comment: if you are asking for a NewGUID on each call, you SHOULDN'T get the same one back. Ever.

Comment: @DavidW & Oscar, please look at what [HidD_GetHidGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does. It is not a Guid generator. *"The HidD_GetHidGuid routine returns the device interfaceGUID for HIDClass devices."*

Comment: Understand, and that's what I thought initially, but the OP's inquiry of validating that it is "valid and correct" made me wonder if my inference about how he was getting GUIDs was correct. If that's what the function is returning, I know of no means to check that it is "valid." That's what the function is returning. It "is what it is." I would expect it to be machine specific.

Comment: I mean, I have a USB mouse and external microchip connected to my PC.I right click on "my computer"-> manage->Device manager->select computer -> right click on computer->properties, scroll down we will find device class GUID. I am getting a different GUID than here

Answer (score 2):

The P/Invoke layer will translate C Guids to C# guids for you. You can call your pinvoke function like so

```
[DllImport("hid.dll", EntryPoint="HidD_GetHidGuid", SetLastError=true)]
static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(out Guid hidGuid);
```

You will then be able to just use the managed [C# Guid class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) and compare against that.

Check out the site [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/hid.HidD_GetHidGuid), they have premade signatures for many windows API calls.

Comment: I have followed this. But still I am not able to "write" to USB device using WriteFile() function. I am checking one by one, so suspected GUID is not correct. Please see my previous question here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673875/c-sharp-writefile-unable-to-write-to-usb-hid-device"

Answer (score 2):

The device GUID isn't the same as the device class interface GUID. For the HID device class pInvoke should return the following:

```
GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID {4D1E55B2-F16F-11CF-88CB-001111000030}
```

More interesting GUID's on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This guide is a good for getting started with HID programming: [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Is-that-you-Writing-Better-Software-for-Cool-USB-Hardware). Source available too.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  Scott Chamberlain, GUID returned by "HidD_GetHidGuid " is it different than system class GUID. Let me know