# What happens when I do ReadFile() on a HID device on Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, hid

When I do a ReadFile/WriteFile on a handle provided by CreateFile(HID_DEVICE_NAME,...), what happens in a terms of HID operations?

Does it issues a direct write/read request to HID device (USB, in my case), or is it transformed somewhere in underlying drivers to read last cached HID report with such ID?

---

*ReadFile call:*

```
syncDevice.OutputReportBuffer[0] = 0;
syncDevice.OutputReportBuffer[1] = reportID;
HANDLE writeHandle = CreateFile(pDevice->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
HANDLE readHandle = CreateFile(pDevice->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
success = WriteFile(writeHandle, (void*) syncDevice.OutputReportBuffer, syncDevice.Caps.OutputReportByteLength, &bytecnt, 0);
success = ReadFile(readHandle, syncDevice.InputReportBuffer, syncDevice.Caps.InputReportByteLength, &bytecnt, 0);
```

Comment: I would expect the CreateFile call to fail; it is my understanding that Windows keeps HID devices open for exclusive access.  At any rate this is unlikely to do anything sensible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston but it works

Comment: @HarryJohnston also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691619/cannot-communicate-successfully-with-usb-hid-device-using-writefile

Comment: Is this a mouse, a keyboard, or something else?

Comment: @HarryJohnston its an AVR-based device which is visible as HID device.

Comment: OK, but does it present itself as a keyboard?  A mouse?  A pen?  There's a list of HID device types at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj126194(v=vs.85).aspx if that's any help.  (That table also indicates which devices are opened for exclusive access and which can be shared.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [USB Complete by Jan Axelson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931448086):

> The Windows HID driver causes the host controller to request Input reports. The driver stores received reports in a buffer. ReadFile retrieves one or more reports from the buffer. If the buffer is empty, ReadFile waits for a report to arrive. In other words, ReadFile doesn’t cause a device to send a report but just reads reports that the driver has requested.
>
> WriteFile sends an Output report. The function uses an interrupt transfer if the HID has an interrupt OUT endpoint and the operating system is later than Windows 98 Gold. Otherwise, WriteFile uses a control transfer with a Set Report request. If using interrupt transfers, WriteFile will wait if the device NAKs. If using control transfers, WriteFile returns with an error code on failure or a timeout.

Comment: Hmm, did you get clearance from the publisher to copy this text?  Avoid this kind of issue by just saying this in your own words, a link to a supporting MSDN article never hurts.

Comment: I cited based on the [community rules on referencing material](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), I could rearrange/substitue words here but I feel this is pretty concise and complete answer. I've flagged my answer to get a moderators opinion.